Freshly planted arborvitae browning
Context: Planted 10 6-foot Thuja Green Giants around a month ago. Hole is as deep as the rootball, but maybe only 2x as wide. The ground was like clay and was very tough to dig, so hoping it’s not a soil issue. However, the trees are starting to yellow and brown at the tips.
I water them about every other day or three days for 15 seconds each on mid hose blast (it’s been very dry here in Delaware). I test the soil before watering by digging with my finger a little to see if it’s dry or moist under the surface.
I can’t tell if these trees are just new and the brown is normal, or there is something I’m doing wrong.
https://imgur.com/a/mq5sjoW
https://imgur.com/a/rZsPPIQ
https://imgur.com/a/nQY8l8Z

Were the trees in pots or balled-and-burlapped? If they were potted, did you break up the rootball when you planted them? Did you use the soil you removed from the hole when you backfilled after planting the tree or did you replace it/amend it?

Got them from Home Depot. They were in a pot. I ruffled up the rootball a little and planted with the soil it came with and backfilled with what I dug.
I found a lot of conflicting answers at the time on what to do with the rootball. Consensus seemed to be just loosen it a bit and should be good.

I don't think you're watering deeply enough - fifteen seconds won't water the entire root ball, so the roots at the bottom are probably not wet at all. Trees should get 1" of water per week, preferably all at once or in two half-inch waterings.
The other issue you have may be soil-related. You have possibly clay soil, and the root ball is almost certainly (well, "almost certainly" if you'd purchased them at a nursery) made up of a fine-grained peat-based soil-less mix. This can cause issues because the soil-less mix and soil have different pore sizes, which affects how water acts when it hits the top of the soil.
I'm pretty sure that the bottom of the root ball is dry as a bone by this time. You need to water each tree for a least half an hour (I'd use a sprinkler) at a fairly slow pressure. Get those roots good and watered, then if you don't have rain, water again three days from now at the same rate and time.
What is brown won't re-green, but you should see no further browning of the arbs.

Awesome thank you so much. I’ll increase my watering schedule to see if it turns around.
It’s tough because they brown/yellow with too much or not enough water haha

They grow in swampy areas, naturally. Indeed, swamp cedar is an alternative name. So underwatering is much more of a problem than overwatering. https://www.coniferousforest.com/northern-white-cedar.htm
